# Fourier Series in any interval [a,b]

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, inner-products

Let $e_n=e^{inx}$ and Fourier coefficients are $\alpha_n= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{e^{inx}}$ where $\overline{e^{inx}}$ is complex conjugate and $f \in  L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.

I’m trying to write a new orthonormal basis and Fourier coefficients according to this new orthonormal basis for $L^2[a,b]$.

I have written if $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $y \in [a,b]$ then $y= \frac{(b-a)x}{2\pi} + \frac{a+b}{2}$. But I cannot obtain orthonormality in my integrals. Could someone please write new orthonormal basis for $[a,b]$

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the Fourier system of functions $u_n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$, defined by
$$u_n(y)=\frac 1{\sqrt{b-a}}e^{  2in\pi\frac{ y}{b-a}}$$ forms an orthonormal basis of $L^2([a,b])$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Could you please explain how did you obtain it with my writtens?